# EnvDTE partial class keyword

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, envdte

I'm introspecting on the code in a project using EnvDTE, and I want to be able to determine if they're a partial class, but it doesn't seem to exist in the namespace.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out

```
if(codeClass.ClassKind == vsCMClassKind.vsCMClassKindPartialClass)
{
   // It is a partial class
}
```

Comment: my pleasure, there seems to only be a handful of us in this space

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C# code model. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228763(VS.80).aspx) msdn article

Comment: ? I've read that article before, but I still don't see where it says anything about determining if the class you're looking at in the code model is a partial or not. The only comment in that article about partials is in relation to how setting elements works (or doesn't) in a partial context.