# VSIX DTE - Create class marked as partial

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, envdte

**Problem:**
Creating a tool similar to the EF model generator, where You can enter tables/columns/relations and it will generate model classes. It is plugin to Visual Studio, running this in VSIX with **DTE** (Development Tools Environment).

I have succesfully created abstract class with properties. Now I want to create other class in same file, which will inherit from the abstract class, and also will be marked as `partial`. I have no idea how to mark the class as a partial, `IntelliSence` is not giving any suitable method/property and search on Google/SO/MSDN has not give me any relevant results.

Some code to get the idea:

```
ProjectItem File = CreateOrFindClassFile(/*params*/); //Creating project file            
if (File != null)
{
    var NS = File.FileCodeModel.AddNamespace("ABC"); //Added namespace ABC

    string ChildClassName = "Xyz";
    string BaseClassName = "XyzBase";


    //Generate base abstract class
    var BaseClass = NS.AddClass(BaseClassName);
    if (BaseClass != null)
    {
        BaseClass.Access = vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic;
        BaseClass.IsAbstract = true;

        //some methods to add variables/methods/properties
    }


    //Generate partial child class
    var ChildClass = lNamespace.AddClass(ChildClassName);
    if (ChildClass != null)
    {
        ChildClass.Access = vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic;
        ChildClass.AddBase(lBaseClassName);

        //TODO: add some code to mark as partial
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there an OOP way (through DTE class tree) to mark a class as `partial`?

Or am I forced to write the class as a string line:

```
NS.GetStartPoint(..)
     .CreateEditPoint()
     .Insert("public partial class Xyz : XyzBase\n{\n}\n");
```

*Note: It works but I'm loosing the control and OOP approach to the classes.*

**Edit1:** Just found some reference on [EnvDTE partial class keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144588/envdte-partial-class-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting your `ChildClass` to `EnvDTE80.CodeClass2` and then use this following property:

```
((EnvDTE80.CodeClass2)ChildClass).ClassKind = EnvDTE80.vsCMClassKind.vsCMClassKindPartialClass;
```

Note that this property might be hidden in the Object Browser or Intellisense.